Oracle 19c Python Pyspark python-oracledb
I am working on an ETL process that is being based on Python/PYSPARK and Oracle 19c (cx_oracle) and push a fair amount of volume - As the DBA I am encountering an issue that appears to be related to Bind Variable Graduation and is impacting performance, depending on the width of the attribute (mainly VARCHAR/CLOB datatypes) it is causing the generation of thousands of child cursors due to the bind variables (over 245 of them in the INSERT) are varying in type/width for each iteration creating a different bind environment and the need to first search for a compatible plan and if not found doing a hard parse which in almost all cases comes up with the same plan (after all, all that changed is the width in most cases).  Turing off Bind Variable Graduation (if it were possible) would only make thing worse and it seems only option is to deal with it at the Python/PySpark level and/or switch tools/approach. I have to imagine that someelse might have encountered this.
Richard
We have been trying to explore option that might allow controling bind variables meta data and avoiding the muttiple plans - we have also been looking at the PySpark documentation and internet searches to identify cause. So far we have not identified anything that addresses the issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

And clarify if you are using cx_Oracle or python-oracledb - your subject doesn't match the question text.   Regarding your problem, have you tried using setinputsizes() ? (I'm not sure how you would do this in pyspark.
